# Games for windows - Error 0x80070660

Tags: windows-8, steam, windows-8-games

I just bought a game on steam and trying to launch it.

This game requiere 'Games for Windows Live' to run but when I want to install it i get this error code : 0x80070660

Do you have any idea to solve this ?

Comment: More information is needed such as operating system, whether by "install it" you mean the game or games for windows live, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[There is a fix](https://www.google.com/search?q="Games+for+Windows+Live"+windows+8)

This is described as a fix for 64-bit Windows (what version is yours?):

1. Uninstall both *Microsoft Games for Windows - LIVE Redistributable* and *Microsoft Games for Windows Marketplace*
2. Reboot
3. Download the GFWL installer from [the XBox site](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient).
4. Right click the above installer, go to properties and change its compatibility to *Windows 7*. Save and exit.
5. Right click the installer, and choose *Run as administrator*
6. After it’s installed, run the GFWL game again. It should now work fine and redownload your profile.

[See video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3wJMmUDO0c)

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with the temp folder:

```
C:\Users\André>err 0x80070660
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WIN32 (0x7), Code 0x660
# for hex 0x660 / decimal 1632
  ERROR_INSTALL_TEMP_UNWRITABLE                                  winerror.h
# The Temp folder is on a drive that is full or is
# inaccessible. Free up space on the drive or verify that you
# have write permission on the Temp folder.
# 1 matches found for "0x80070660"
```

Look if your account has writing permissions to the folders C:\Windows\Temp and the Temp folder under AppData\Local .